# How do I impliment [example.text intValue]?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I am making an app that tells you how much medicine an animal needs based on their weight, etc. For the LRS (a type of medicine), the formula is

> (30 * weight * factor + 70) * factor + dehydration + weight

So for the code, I typed `lrs = (30 * [weight.text intValue] + 70) * [factor.text intValue] + [weight.text intValue] * [deh.text intValue] * 10 + [losses.text intValue];`, but the compiler is saying that there is "Use of unresolved identifier intValue".

Everywhere I looked online, it says that `[example.text intValue]`takes a number value from the input in a UITextField. Is there something wrong with my code? Thanks!

**PS-** I am only twelve years old, I learned everything I know about code online, and I have been trying to solve my problem for nearly 2 hours. If you answer, can your answer please be thorough and easy to understand?

Also, here is *all* my code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var animalNum: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var logLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var resetButton: UIButton!


@IBOutlet weak var weight: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var deh: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var losses: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var factor: [UITextField]!

@IBOutlet weak var lrs24: UILabel!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Handle the text field’s user input through delegate callbacks.
    animalNum.delegate = self
}

// MARK: UITextFieldDelegate

func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    // Hide the keyboard.
    textField.resignFirstResponder()
    return true
}

func textFieldDidEndEditing(textField: UITextField) {
    logLabel.text = textField.text
}

// MARK: Actions
@IBAction func setDefaultLabelText(sender: UIButton) {
    logLabel.text = "Default Text"
}


@IBAction func textFieldsDidEndEditing(sender: AnyObject) {

    lrs24.label = (30 * [weight.text ,intValue] + 70) * &factor+       &weight * &deh * 10 + &losses;



    //(30 * &weight + 70) * &factor + &weight * &deh * 10 + &losses
}



// MARK: properties

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[weight.text intValue]` is Objective-C code. The Swift equivalent would be `(weight.text as NSString).intValue` (the `as NSString` is necessary because swift Strings aren't implicitly converted to NSString).

Or even more Swifty, `Int(weight.text)`, which gives you an Optional<Int> rather than returning 0 when the string isn't a well-formed number.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know that it was so simple :)